# How to show that multiplication of matrices is associative and distributive over addition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to show that multiplication of matrices, when defined, is associative and distributive over addition. Let $R$ be a ring, and the set of all $n \times m$ matrices over $R$.

Comment: C = AB, then the ith row and , jth column of C is given by, $\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} b_{kj}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Association: if $D = ABC$, then $D_{ij} = \sum_p \sum_q A_{ip} B_{pq} C_{qj} = \sum_p A_{ip}\left(\sum_q B_{pq}C_{qj}\right) = \sum_p A_{ip} \left(BC\right)_{pj} = A(BC)$

Similarly,

$D_{ij} = \sum_p \sum_q A_{ip} B_{pq} C_{qj} = \sum_q\left(\sum_pA_{ip} B_{pq}\right)C_{qj} = \sum_q\left(AB\right)_{iq}C_{qj} = (AB)C$

2) Distribution can also be proved in the same way, by writing out the expression for each matrix element.

Comment: can you show also for the distributive? it can help me to check my answer..thanks

Comment: If $D = A(B+C)$, then $D = \sum_p A_{ip}(B_{pj} + C_{pj}) = \sum_p ( A_{ip}B_{pj} + A_{ip}C_{pj})$. When you expand the sum over $P$ into two separate sums, you get the result $D = AB + AC$.